# Secondary import when using Firebase?

Tags: node.js, firebase, es6-modules

Why do we need to import what seems like the same module twice when using Firebase?

```
import { firestore, initializeApp } from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';
```

Would be interesting to hear why this case may come up in general `node/js` `es6` modules and not just here.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do something like this:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore'; 
import 'firebase/auth';
```

The first line imports the main Firebase dependency, so that you call `firebase.initializeApp(...)`.

The second and third line then import specific Firebase product SDKs on top of that, so that you can access `firebase.firestore()` and `firebase.auth()`.

This pulls in the minimal amount of JavaScript that is needed for my specific app.

---

Your first line pulls in the SDKs for all Firebase projects, and then imports a few objects out of there. This is quite wasteful, as you're unlikely to be using *all* products in an app.

I'm actually not sure what the second line does in your case.

Comment: Yes, thank you - the above code is not mine, it is what is found in almost every guide. I just cannot understand why the second import is needed, I read something about side effects but cannot find what this means.